# Trying to make a 3AA battery case

Tags: battery

I have requirement to create a device which works on 3AA battery and uses a small enclosure. When all the items are put inside the enclosure, only about 31x31x60 space is left.

So all the readily available 3xAA battery case were out. They are mostly linear and are of sizes 57x48x20 or so. I have the metal contacts needed to create the battery holder:

[image]

The idea I have is to make something like this:

[image]
[image]

The case would be open from top side, and would have side walls and bottom wall. Its almost like a "U" shaped case. The easiest way to prototype this  would be to get acrylic sheet cut but once the walls are all made, I've the next step to "fasten" the metal spring contacts. I have following options:

1. Araldite
2. Make another thin wall parallel to the end of the U shaped side wall, to "hold" the plates.
3. Make holes made on the metal spring contacts and then screw them via m1.5/m2 to the U wall.

In terms of ease, 1>3>2. However I dont know if option 1 to glue using araldite is going to work well - will it cause any leakage current to go higher (I doubt, just double checking). And I'm not too sure if araldite is stable and strong enough for this metal/acrylic bonding for 3-4 years life. Option 3 is definitely a possiblity but asthetically not pleasing. And option 2 is lot of extra work, but would just work.

Please let me know what you guys think.

Comment: 31*31*60 inches gives you lots of space...

Comment: Would something like [this holder](https://www.batteryholders.com/part.php?pn=BC3AAGW) work well enough for you? That's just what Google gives me for "3x AA triangle battery holder".

Comment: For this u shaped thing yes. Almost just about

Comment: That triangle won't work. The holder would be set inside. The batteries should be inserted directly from the opening at the top and there is no way to rotate the holder inside

Comment: Speaking from experience of poorly designed battery powered things - an entirely removable triangle holder (whole thing comes out, wires adequate length for that,  access is easy) beats the heck out of fighting to get batteries into a difficult to access fixed holder or compartment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would probably be a better fit for [electronics.se]. I see nothing there _against_ this type of question (without the "what do you think") and I've seen a number of design questions there.

Comment: There are dozens of battery - case designs over at thingiverse.com, so if you have access to a printer, that might be the quickest way.

Comment: Check out how one of those little LED flashlights do it.

Comment: Guys, instead of answering my question, I've gotten so many opinion. Trust me, I've explored everything possible for last 1 week and arrived this is what I need. And I hope instead of closing the question, if someone could just answer the question! I know what I'm ding guys, trust me. I've to prototype something with enclosure which is readily available, and this is my situation. I can't do printers, nothing. This is what I've to do.

Comment: Making case come out doesn't beat heck anything in aan end product. Maybe okay for pet project. It looks immature and shabby in a prototype product as well. So I don't want to do it.

Comment: The questions I've posed here don't make any sense for electronics stack exchange

Answer (score 2):

I've used 3xAA to D battery adapters for powering devices. The enclosure is professional in appearance and permits one to attach wiring as needed, or to use single contact attachments in the same manner as that of a D battery.

[image: 3xAA to D adapter]

The image above is from [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BDK27FQ) but there are many sources of adapters of this nature.

It's easier to find AAA mini-flashlights, so I'm using this as an example only. I've opened up the cheap/free flashlight and soldered wires to the housing to create a 3xAAA enclosure with convenient power switch. You didn't ask for such a mechanism, but it was referenced in the comments and is a valid solution if you can locate a 3xAA flashlight, otherwise, the adapter provides an off-the-shelf solution to your objective.

Comment: The problem is these are availabile only for Aaa and not for aa. I've a low power device on 3AA. This usually is easy to find for AAA.

Comment: Besides this is for Parallel and I want for series

Comment: You can remove the metal portions and re-align for series use. These units in the images are AA sized.

Comment: If you notice closely its not easy. The entire plate is going to be replaced with something custom. The plate is conducting, not something where simply changing spring placement would solve the problem.